# RSA public key security issue

Tags: rsa, public-key

The public key for RSA is $[e,n]$. Since $n = p * q$, are $p$ and $q$ already exposed because it takes no effort to figure out $p$ and $q$ from $n$?

Comment: No research effort whatsoever was made. Proper tagging is not enough!

Comment: No they are not, getting p,q from n is not trivial

Answer (score 4):

If I right understood your question, you think that from N it is easy to compute $p$ and $q$. But it is not true.

For computing $p$ and $q$ from $N$, you need to solve [factorization problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization). And this is very difficult. If $N$ small number, then you can use brute force. But when it comes to RSA, $N$ is a very big number. And it will take many hundreds years to compute $p$ and $q$ this way.

But you can use one of sub exponential algorithm, for example [quadratic sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve). It is one of the fastest factorization algorithm right now.  for big $N$ (1024 bits or more) this method is not practical. That is why, knowledge $N$ will not give you help to reveal $p$ and $q$.

But as soon as a practical method is found, RSA will be absolutely weak, because everyone would be capable to compute $\varphi(N)=(p-1)(q-1)$ and everyone would be capable to compute the secret exponent $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(N)$.

Comment: Writing nice formulas is easy: $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(N)$ is just `$d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(N)$`; an important point is that this $d$ will be _a working_ private exponent; however it is not guaranteed to be _the_ private exponent; there are several equally fine private exponents.

Comment: @fgrieu Thank you. It is really easy:) I didn`t get your remark about several exponents. Do you mean that every $d$ such as $ed=k\varphi(N)+1$ will be good private exponent?

Comment: Yes, every $d$ such as $e⋅d=k⋅φ(N)+1$ will be good private exponent. And there typically are others. If $N=p⋅q$ with $p$ and $q$ large distinct primes, one can use $\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ which is also [$\lambda(N)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), and is smaller than $φ(N)$. That's what the [de-facto-standard definition of RSA](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/pkcs/files/h11300-wp-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard.pdf) does. It allows smaller $d$, that often are slightly more efficient.